# Lax's proof of a property of principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

There's a section in Peter Lax's *Linear Algebra* (2nd edition) that I am struggling to understand. I think it involves at least one typo, so let me write it out here exactly as it is in the book. Lax has just established that if $\lambda$ is a simple root of $\chi_A(x)$, then one of the principal minors of $A-\lambda I$ has nonzero determinant. Then he continues (p. 131):

"Let A be (a matrix with $a$ as a simple root of its characteristic polynomial) and take the eigenvalue $a$ to be zero. Then one of the principal $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors of $A$, say the $i$th, has nonzero determinant. We claim that the $i$th component of an eigenvector $h$ of $A$ pertaining to the eigenvalue $a$ is nonzero. Suppose it were denote (sic) by $h^{(i)}$ the vector obtained from $h$ by omitting the $i$th component, and by $A_ji$ (sic) the $i$th principal minor of $A$. Then $h^{(i)}$ satisfies $$A_{ii}h^{(i)}=0."$$

Huh? Why should $A_{ii}h^{(i)}=0$? If I am to understand by $A_{ii}$ the $i$th principal minor of $A$, which results from omitting the $i$th row and $i$th column, then this statement seems false. For a dumb counterexample, let $A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1 \\ 2&-2\end{matrix}\right]$ and $h=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\end{matrix}\right]$. Then $A_{ii}h^{(i)}\neq 0$.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: At least one typo is an understatement. Clearly whoever was paid by the editor to copy-edit that passage should be fired. But did you really check that you rendered it as it stands? $A_ji$ is weird, even if you replace the $j$ by $i$.

Comment: I haven't this book, but I found on the internet a [review](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/pdfiles/lax.pdf) by David Watkins of Washington State University. According to him, "the book contains many, many misprints. Most of them are harmless, but one or two of them caused me considerable puzzlement."

Comment: @user1551, Yes, I've found that to be true. On the positive side, it contains a whole heap of linear algebra material that I hadn't seen in textbooks like Friedberg, Strang, Roman, etc. For instance, the material on matrix calculus was new to me, also the simple theorem that two diagonalizable matrices commute iff they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he meant a proof by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that the $i$-th component of $h$ **is** zero. Then $Ah=0$ implies that $A_{ii}h^{(i)}=0$. As $\det(A_{ii})\neq0$, it follows that $A_{ii}$ is invertible and $h^{(i)}=0$. Therefore $h=0$, contradicting that $h$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: I think you're exactly right! Thanks